# Error while trying to download Files using Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I have been getting the below error when i try to download file from a https URL. I am using Power Shell 3.0

Shell Script

```
$Username = 'user'
$Password = 'password'
$Url = "url"
$Path = "path"
$WebClinet = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $Url, $Path )
```

Error :

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:7 char:1
+ $WebClient.DownloadFile( $Url, $Path )

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not PowerShell 1.0, please inspect `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` to get the actual version

Comment: My bad! Its 3.0.. Any suggestions to the error I described?

Comment: @Dhruv does the user you are providing credentials for have access rights to _both_ the `$Url` and `$Path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap you existing powershell code in a try catch block and write out the exception details in order to understand what actual error is causing the problem.

```
Try
{
    $Username = 'user'
    $Password = 'password'
    $Url = "url"
    $Path = "path"
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
    $WebClient.DownloadFile( $Url, $Path )
}
Catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
}
```

And also there is a typo in your code. Check your variable names.

Comment: Thanks ! The '$Path' throws an access issue.

Comment: If possible, try to  update your questions with the error message to clarify it further if that is necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: This is the error that i get. But I am executing the Powershell script from the same path and it has the access.       System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to
the path '' is denied.

Comment: Access issue is fixed.. but now i get the below error                                                              System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:

Comment: +1 for the comment on how to catch and write out exceptions and their stacktrace.  I'm new to PS & Windows, and this was incredibly helpful in figuring out my error.

Answer (score 0):

Added the below commands to the script and it works fine now

```
   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```